# Question about changing objects opacity using a UI Button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Inside an empty gameobject have 3 cubes: *redCube*, *blueCube*, & *greenCube*. Each cube has its own standard transparent material: *red_mat*, *blue_mat*, and *green_mat*.

Attach a script to the empty gameobject and add a UI button (cannot use toggle button) to the scene. When UI button is clicked all 3 cubes change opacity from `1f` to `0.5f`. When UI button is clicked again, all 3 cubes change opacity from `0.5f` back to `1f`.

The problem is when I click the UIbutton once, all cubes opacity become `0.5f` (so far so good...). When I click the UI button again, all cubes' opacity change back to `1f`, **BUT** all cube materials turn to white and do not go back to their original colour. I need someone to show me how it works.

How to only change the Alpha channel value when I click the UI button?
I have tried sharedmaterial/sharedmaterials. But, it did not work. Maybe I was using it incorrectly.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class OpacityController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float opacity = 0.5f; //opacity control
    public Component[] renderer; //get all the children renderer component

    int i = 0; //toggle the button

    void Start()
    {
        renderer = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();

    }

    public void OnOpacityButton()
    {
        Color color1 = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
        color1.a = 0.5f;
        Color color2 = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
        color2.a = 1f;

        i++;
        if (i % 2 == 1) //toggle the button
        {
            foreach (Renderer col in renderer)
                col.sharedMaterial.color = color1;

        } else
        {
            foreach (Renderer col in renderer)
                col.sharedMaterial.color = color2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `material` rather than `sharedmaterial` if you want to change material of a specific game object. I would suggest using a `bool` instead of an `int` to keep track of the toggle state.

I have refactored your code with a few other improvements and comments:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class OpacityController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float opacity = 0.5f; //opacity control
    public Component[] renderers; //get all the children renderer component

    private bool toggle = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
    }

    public void OnOpacityButton()
    {
        // invert the toggle value
        toggle = !toggle;

        // select the opacity value using the trinary operator
        float newOpacity = toggle ? opacity : 1f;

        // assign the new opacity to all the renderers
        foreach (Renderer renderer in renderers)
        {
            // copy the current color and assign a new opacity to it.
            Color newColor = renderer.material.color; 
            newColor.a = newOpacity;

            // assign the new color to material rather than sharedmaterial to change only the current material
            renderer.material.color = newColor; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou @Tedium Interactive ..This is very helpful with clear explanation. Beginner learning here.  I want to make sure I understand your logic here.....  What you were doing was storing the original Color in newColor = renderer.material.color    And then modify the opacity in newColor.a    And then reassign the new value to renderer,material.color = newColor. And everything is triggered by the condition toggle=!toggle

Comment: Sounds like you got it @catcattt.